# React Router - How to pass previous location pathname to current

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Is it possible to pass the previous path to current location?

For instance, I have 2 Routes. `Home /`  and `Profile /profile`

If I am In `Profile` route and I go to `Home` route, now I am inside Home route, how do I get access to previous pathname which was `/profile` ?

Something like:

```
const Home = (props) => {
   console.log(props.location.state.previousPath) // How to access previous path? 
}
```

This is how I structure my router with custom routes

```
const App = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <main className="min-h-screen">
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
         <PublicRoute path={ROUTE.REGISTER} component={Register} />
         <PublicRoute path={ROUTE.LOGIN} component={Login} />
         <ProtectedRoute path={ROUTE.HOME} exact component={Home} />
         <ProtectedRoute path={ROUTE.PROFILE} component={Profile} />
         <Route component={PageNotFound} />
       </Switch>
     </main>
   </Router>
)
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuth, component: Component, path, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            component={(props) => {
                // ANY WAY TO ACCESS IT HERE THEN PASS IT TO COMPONENT?
                return isAuth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={LOGIN} />
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally solved it. To anyone wondering how to pass state to route, this is how I did it.

By setting state when using `Link` or `NavLink`

<= v5 usage:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();

<Link 
    to={{ 
    pathname: '/', 
    state: { from: pathname } // or any property you like to add
  }}
> 
   Home
</Link>
```

Or with `history.push` method

```
const history = useHistory();
const { pathname } = useLocation();

history.push('/', { from: pathname, someOtherProp: '' }) 
                  // second argument for passing state
```

Now I have access to states passed to route

```
const Home = (props) => {
   console.log(props.location.state.from);
}
```

**Update:**
On react router v6 there have been a few syntax changes.
Check on this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-chihiro-y7l7r?file=/src/App.js) for example

v6 usage:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { pathname } = useLocation();

// Using hook
navigate("/", { state: { previousPath: pathname } });

// using Link component
<Link to="/" state={{ previousPath: pathname }}>
```

Comment: I am still not able to access location.state.. Can you show how your routes look? How do you pass along the location?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Just the normal setup of routes really.
But with v6 of react-router, there's a slight changes.
Check this sandbox [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-chihiro-y7l7r?file=/src/App.js) for an example

Comment: I figured out why: you have to do `<Link to="/" state={{ previousPath: pathname }}>` instead of `<Link 
    to={{ 
    pathname: '/', 
    state: { from: pathname } // or any property you like to add
  }}
> `

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra, on that Codesandbox that you shared, the path returns undefined. Were you able to make it work?

Comment: @santoros It is undefined because the state wasn't set from the previous location. If you would take a look on the ```Dummy``` page , there isn't a state set from using the ```Link``` component ```<Link to="/">``` unlike from using it on the ```Profile``` page ```<Link to="/" state={{ previousPath: pathname }}>```

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra, thanks. I noticed that and I added the state, but still I keep getting undefined.